# Computing $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n2^n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Challenging Integral:

> \begin{align}
> I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx&=6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{81}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\&\quad+\frac{21}8\ln^22\zeta(3)-\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac15\ln^52
> \end{align}

---

I came across this integral while i was trying to calculate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n2^n}$, proposed by Cornel on his FB page [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1601595849937207&set=pob.100002604219021&type=3&theater), but he has not revealed his solution yet.

The integral is related to the sum through the identity ( see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293274)):
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^a(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=(-1)^a a! \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a+1)}}{n2^n}$$

With $a=3$, We get $\quad\displaystyle I=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n2^n}\quad$.

The way I computed this integral is really long as it's based on values of tough alternating Euler sums which themselves long to calculate. I hope we can find other approaches that save us such tedious calculations. Any way, here is my approach:

Using the identity from [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292603): $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3(1-x)\ dx=-\frac{H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{n}$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ then summing both sides from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$, gives:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{(-x)^{n}}{n}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^3}{n^2}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}
\end{align}

We have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^3}{n^2}&=-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{21}{8}\ln^22\zeta(3)\\&\quad+\frac{27}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac94\zeta(5)-\frac15\ln^52
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}&=4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+4\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac23\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac74\ln^22\zeta(3)\\&\quad-\frac{15}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{23}8\zeta(5)+\frac2{15}\ln^52
\end{align}

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{21}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

The proof of the first and second sum can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3254834) and the third sum can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3255561).

By substituting these three sums,we get the closed form of $I$.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to compute $\int_0^\frac12 \frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{x}dx$? It's the last piece that I need in order to solve the integral in another way. The case where the upper bound is $1$ instead of $\frac12$ is quite easy:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3233489/515527, however this causes me some problems.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like this:
$$I=-6\ln 2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+6\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-6\int_0^\frac12 \frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{x}dx$$ 
Hope I copied it right from my notebook. Of course the values for the dilogarithm and trilogarithm are known, and can be further reduced.

Comment: @Zacky the integral you mentioned was proposed by Cornel before he proposed the sum I linked. They are much related and I think Cornel evaluated the integral first then the sum . He has not revealed the solution of both yet and still standing as a challenge. I tried a lot for that integral but kept going in circles.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input.

Comment: Your super hard to crack Euler sum can be expressed as $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(4)}_n}{n 2^n} = \operatorname{Li}_5 \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) + \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_4 (x)}{1 - x} \, dx.$$ Expressing the polylog appearing in the integral as a series, followed by integrating by parts 3 times leads me down the garden path to the following term: $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx.$$ But what is to be done with this term?

Comment: @Zacky check this link https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1600245036738955&set=pob.100002604219021&type=3&theater

Comment: @omegadot yes and that integral is tough.

Comment: When I first saw this question a couple months ago, I remember thinking I'd be shocked if no one's ever asked about this integral before. What I just realized this morning is that apparently *I* asked about this [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552441/another-polylog-integral?rq=1). Palm $\rightarrow$ face.

Answer (score 2):

This integral was solved by @Song [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325928) along with a related integral using a magical algebraic identity

$$2a^3b = -{b^4 \over 2} -{b^4 + 6a^2b^2\over 2} + 3(a^3b+ab^3) - (a-b)^3b$$

with $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$